# how to load dropdown value based on another dropdown value

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two dropdownlist like country and state.I need to load states based on country value.

I create ajax Call and execute countrydropdown's change Event.

Now My question is how to load state dropdown based on country dropdown value

```
Model

public SelectList statename { get; set; }
public string selectedvalue { get; set; }


Controller

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult form(displayModel disp)
        {
            var display = new displayModel();
            List<string> state = new List<string>();
            if (disp.selectedvalue == "India")
            {
                state.Add("TN");
                state.Add("KL");
                state.Add("UP");
            }
            display.statename = new SelectList(state, "--select--");
            return View(display);
        }
View

@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.statename)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.statename, Model.statename, new { id="dropstate"})

 $("#dropdown1").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/form",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    selectedvalue: $("#dropdown1 option:selected").text()
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);

                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This link should help in doing the same, 
http://devingredients.com/2011/05/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-with-jquery/

However instead of hardcoding the values as mentioned in the above link, you could make an ajax call to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call like this to call a controller method that will return the json on behalf of selected id and then populate the results in the dropdown

```
Controller:

public JsonResult GetStateList() {
  var list = new List<ListItem>() {
    new ListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "VA" },
    new ListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "MD" },
    new ListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "DC" }
  };
  return this.Json(list);
}


$(function() {
$("#dropdown1").change(function () {
    $.getJSON("/Home/GetStateList", { Id: $("#dropdown1 option:selected").val() },
       function(fooList) {
           $("#state").empty();
           $.each(fooList, function(i, foo) {
               $("#state").append(""+ foo.Value + "");
           });
       });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the `selectedCountryId` to the **Controller** and you can populate the `State` list items as **JSON** data.

**Ajax Code :**

```
    $('#dropdown1').change(function () {
        var selectedCountryId = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("form")', { countryId: selectedCountryId }, function (data) {
            var select = $('#dropstate');
            select.empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, sta) {
                select.append(
                    $('<option/>')
                        .attr('value', sta.Value)
                        .text(sta.Text)
                );
            });                
        });
    });
```

**Controller Code:**

```
    public ActionResult form(int countryId)
    {   
        //Here you can check the countryId & if any logic you want  
        //Or Else you can call the service method here and opcode StateListItems, 
        //If so then you have make a little change to the below JSON data           
        var stateList = new List<StateItem>()
                      {
                          new ListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "AndraPradesh" },
                          new ListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "Karnataka" },
                          new ListItem() { Value = "3", Text = "TamilNadu" }
                      };
        var rows = service.ToArray();
        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```